# Не подключает базу MySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Имею HTTP-сервер Apache на Raspberry pi.
Пытаюсь подключить созданную базу.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>
```

И сам connect.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("Белый IP адрес:3306","Пользователь","Пароль");
if (!$link) {
echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
mysqli_select_db("articles" ,$link)
?>
```

Порт 3306 проброшен в роутере.
В итоге получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL. Код ошибки errno:
>   2002 Текст ошибки error: Connection refused. Как пофиксить?

Comment: Проверьте настройки mySql, скорее всего он принимает запросы только с localhost. Во всяком случае это очень часто так "по умолчанию".

Comment: Нет соединения, проверьте ваши настройки. Если настройки соединения верные, значит что то его разрывает, пробуйте переподключаться http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.ping.php

Comment: /etc/mysql/my.cnf действительно по умолчанию. Что мне нужно прописать там?

Comment: Локально подключается под этим пользователем? Что указано в свойстве `socket`  `[client]` и `[mysqld]`?

Comment: Прописал вместо "Белый IP адрес:3306" localhost. Работает как локально так и удалённо.